# Ubuntu 18.04 Unmount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root for fsck

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, lvm

so I am having a problem booting my newly upgraded 18.04 installation, and all the solutions that I see are pointing me toward doing `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` from recovery mode.  The only problem is that in recovery mode, I run that and it says `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is mounted. cannot continue, aborting.`  How do I successfully unmount this filesystem so that I can fix it?